# Using global variables to keep values of window dimensions

Tags: c++, qt, oop, global-variables

I'm programming a game using Qt and a question came to my in mind. I need to keep track of the dimensions of the main window, and several objects need to know these values (collision detector, settings handler, the window itself etc.). It is important that the dimensions can be changed during the runtime.

Is using global variables a bad practice in this case? What are good design solutions for this problem? It would be a pain to pass these values by reference using the classes constructors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Window dimensions are attributes of a window, and are provided by Qt. You don't need to "keep" their values, just access the size of appropriate window.

It would of course help to abstract out a base object that keeps the state of your game. Then simply forward size changes from the window to that base object. It could be as simple as the following:

```
class GameView : public QWidget {
  typedef QWidget base_class;
  GameState * m_state;
public:
  GameView(GameState * state, QWidget * parent = 0) : m_state(state), QWidget(parent) {
    m_state->setSize(size());
  }
protected:
  void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent * ev) {
    m_state->setSize(size());
    base_class::resizeEvent(ev);
  }
};
```

The game state object can then inform relevant subobjects about the change (the collision detector, etc.).

Comment: This pattern calls "dependecy injection". It is good practice for such cases: 1) You implement class which implements your logic. 2) You provide this interface to other classes.

Answer (score 1):

The global variables as always are symptomatic of poor design and a lack of decoupling. That's your real issue. If you later need to modify any of these global variables or how they're intended to be used, then several different classes will have to be changed in order to accommodate that. We'd have to see your design in more detail to properly criticize it, but that's the gist of it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not specifically familiar with Qt, but I have some experience with C++ development/design.

I agree you don't want to be stuck passing around dimensions, as it's a lot of work and error prone.  I think a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) would be an appropriate pattern to apply. You can use a class that is initialized only once to encapsulate the dimensions, and that class can provide a single point of variation for those values.  Suppose you need to rename them, add another value, or change the types: you can often still support the same interface and prevent rippling code changes.  It's possible to use a static accesser/initializer to implement such a class in C++.  It's worth noting that some will consider such a pattern to also be poor code design, but when used appropriately, I think it would meet your needs.